# Ways to set per instance __call__?

Tags: python

What I want to do is something like:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self):
        print "f"
    def g(self):
        print "g"


# programatically set the "default" operation
fer=Foo()
fer.__call__=fer.f

# a different instance does something else as its
# default operation
ger=Foo()
ger.__call__=ger.g

fer()  # invoke different functions on different
ger()  # objects depending on how they were set up.
```

But as of 2.7 (which I'm currently using) I can't do this, the attempts at `fer()`
raise an exception.

Is there a way to, in effect, set a per instance `__call__` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal stuff with `types.MethodType` unfortunately doesn't work here since `__call__` is a special method.

From the data model:

> Class instances are callable only when the class has a `__call__()` method; x(arguments) is a shorthand for `x.__call__(arguments)`.

This is *slightly* ambiguous as to what is actually called, but it's clear that your class *needs* to have a `__call__` method.

You'll need to create some sort of hack:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self):
        print "f"
    def g(self):
        print "g"

    def __call__(self):
        return self.__call__()

f = Foo()
f.__call__ = f.f
f()

g = Foo()
g.__call__ = g.g
g()
```

Careful with this though, it'll result in an infinite recursion if you don't set a `__call__` on an instance before you try to call it.

Note that I don't actually recommend calling the magic attribute that you rebind `__call__`.  The point here is to demonstrate that python translates: `f()` into `f.__class__.__call__(f)` and so there's nothing you can do to change it on a per-instance basis.  the class's `__call__` will be called no matter what you do -- You just need to do something to change the behavior of the class's `__call__` per-instance which is easily achieved.

---

You could use a setter type thing to actually create methods on your class (rather than simple functions) -- and of course that could be turned into a property:

```
import types
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self):
        print "f"
    def g(self):
        print "g"

    def set_func(self,f):
        self.func = types.MethodType(f,self)

    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.func(*args,**kwargs)

f = Foo()
f.set_func(Foo.f)
f()

def another_func(self,*args):
    print args

f.set_func(another_func)
f(1,2,3,"bar")
```

Comment: If i add `self.__call__=self.f` inside `__init__` I should be able to avoid the infinite regress problem.

Comment: @Barkuiu -- Yes, I don't actually recommend using `__call__` as the name.  I'll edit to make that more clear.  The point was to demonstrate that python translates `instance()` to `instance.__class__.__call__(instance)` *before* that line is even run which is why we can get away with rebinding `__call__` on the instance and have it still work.

Comment: Setting up a convention (or even a class) where the objects have a `call_impl` member (which is a name that makes sense to me at least) which is called inside `__call__`, and then set/reset that function, seems like a good way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You might be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Since python allows procedural creation of classes you could write code like that:

```
>>> def create_class(cb):
...     class Foo(object):
...         __call__ = cb
...     return Foo
... 
>>> Foo1 = create_class(lambda self: 42)
>>> foo1 = Foo1()
>>> foo1()
>>> Foo2 = create_class(lambda self: self.__class__.__name__)
>>> foo2 = Foo2()
>>> foo2()
```

Please note thought that Foo1 and Foo2 do not have a common base class in this case. So `isinstance` and `issubclass` will not work. If you need them to have a common base class I would go for the following code:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def create_subclass(cls, cb):
...          class SubFoo(cls):
...               __call__ = cb
...          return SubFoo
... 
>>> Foo1 = Foo.create_subclass(lambda self: 42)
>>> foo1 = Foo1()
>>> foo1()
>>> Foo2 = Foo.create_subclass(lambda self: self.__class__.__name__)
>>> foo1 = Foo2()
>>> foo2()
'Foo'
>>> issubclass(Foo1, Foo)
True
>>> issubclass(Foo2, Foo)
True
```

I really like the second way as it provides a clean class hierarchy and looks quite clean to me.

Comment: I like this and I don't like it.  Something seems overly wasteful about creating a new class just to override a single method -- On the other hand, it seems quite elegant and clean so I'll give it a +1.  Nice work thinking in a different box than I did :)

Comment: Doing metaclass programing is something I wouldn't have thought of, but I believe that it would preclude re-setting the function; which is not what I'm going for, but could be a useful constraint in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._callable = lambda s: None
    def f(self):
        print "f"
    def set_callable(self, func):
        self._callable = func
    def g(self):
        print "g"
    def __call__(self):
        return self._callable()
d = Foo()
d.set_callable(d.g)
```

Comment: setter or dunderscores .. in this case i prefer setters